# Windows reg export console sessionid

Tags: windows, администрирование, zabbix

Помогите разобраться с правами на экспорт веток реестра...
Для примера в реестре создаю такую ветку:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyTEST
```

в которой создаю строковый параметр `mystring` со значением `ABCD`
Этот ключ легко читается командой

```
 reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyTEST /s
```

получаю ответ

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyTEST
    mystring    REG_SZ    ABCD
```

Все корректно.

Дополнительно на этой же машине работает Zabbix-агент (запущен от Администратора), который запускает такую же команду

```
system.run["reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyTEST /s"]
```

и при этом получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка: Не удается найти указанный раздел или параметр в реестре

Таким образом в режиме `SessionID = 1` (пользовательский режим) ветка есть, а в режиме `SessionId =0` (службы) данной ветки нет.

Кто может подсказать как из консольного режима (или от другого пользователя) увидеть все ветки реестра?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что дело тут в разной разрядности программ, которые вы используете. Дело в том, что 32- и 64-разрядные программы используют разные ветки `HKLM\Software`. Если вы создали ветку `HKLM\Software\MyTest` 32-разрядной программа, то 64-разрядная ее не найдет, потому что ее ветка `HKLM\Software` будет переотображена на `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` (или наоброт, там довольно запутанно, не помню точно).

В общем, разберитесь, в какой именно ветке вы создаете свой ключ, и обращайтесь именно туда по полному пути.